# How to archive certain rows to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to move my team's productivity to another sheet via Apps Script.

On the sheet "Prod" you can see the weekly productivity the team has put in. The "Approved" column has checkboxes where the work can be manually verified.
[image: Prod Sheet]

The second sheet is the "Archives" sheet. Where the Apps Script will move all of the responses from the "Prod" sheet over there.
[image: Archives Sheet]

**Apps Script Code**

```
function archive() {
  // Get the information
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Prod');
  var a = ss.getSheetByName('Archives');
  var data = s.getRange('A2:F').getValues();
  
  // Archive the results
  for (i in data) {
    var write = data[i];
    a.appendRow(write);
  }
  
  // Clear the results
  s.getRange('A2:E').clear();
  s.getRange('F2:F').uncheck();
}
```

### **The Problem**

The code works perfectly fine, however, when it is moving the "Prod" responses over to the "Archives" it includes the empty rows. This is because in the "Approved" column the checkbox is technically false, which means it's included. How would I go about changing the code to only transfer rows that have data in the A column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the values from `Prod` to `Archives` when the value of column "A" in `Prod` is not empty.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, all values of `var data = s.getRange('A2:F').getValues();` is copied to `Archives`. So in this case, it is required to check the column "A" of `data`.
- When `appendRow()` is used in a loop, the process cost will be high. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function archive() {
  // Get the information
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Prod');
  var a = ss.getSheetByName('Archives');
  var data = s.getRange('A2:F').getValues();
  
  // Archive the results <--- I modified this part.
  var copyValues = data.filter(([a]) => a.toString() != "");
  a.getRange(a.getLastRow() + 1, 1, copyValues.length, copyValues[0].length).setValues(copyValues);
  
  // Clear the results
  s.getRange('A2:E').clear();
  s.getRange('F2:F').uncheck();
}
```

#### References:

- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)